# Deploying a C# wpf with Visual Studio 2012 without its publishing option

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, deployment, inno-setup

I want to deploy a C# wpf application which I made with Visual Studio 2012 without publishing option there ?

I thought to deploy the release folder with [Inno setup compiler](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php)

But it it slow when starting the application for the first time ?

What is the best option I can do ?

Comment: so the problem is that the first start is slow? What are you installing together with your app? (If the framework is on the target machine and you don't use 3rd party tools like CrystalReports there is no need to do anything more then copy the files!)

Comment: framework is on the target machine. I connect to a SQLite database when loading. It is the only thing.

Answer (score 0):

If your app doesn't have a splash screen you could add one to make it appear more responsive when first launched. Adding a splash screen in WPF is very easy. Here's a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656886%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Also Google ".Net Cold Start". Here's a MS [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656914%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the subject.

Inno is a very easy way to deploy your app,

Comment: Thanks for the info. Still I do not know whether it is the right method of deploying.

Comment: Inno has been around for a long time and I've used it for installing production apps (managed and native) for years. We use if for the initial installation and then use an auto-update mechanism going forward.

Comment: So I am going to deploy my application by giving the release folder of the Visual Studio Solution. But I hope I do not want all the files there because some may for debugging purposes. So what are the files that I can delete to reduce the size ?